# Узнать функцию из которой был вызван __getitem__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
class DictStruct(dict):

'''...'''

    # Автоматически создаёт объекты класса Dict
    # Если они есть в пути, Например:
    # При struct['dict1']['dict2'] = ...
    # добавит dict1 даже если его нету
    #
    # Нужно чтоб при присваивании дополнение
    # недостающих блоков работали с созданием Dict-ов,
    # но при выводе возвращало ошибку если ключ отсутствует

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self.__dict__.keys():
             return self.__missing__(key)
    return self.__dict__[key]

def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    pass

def __missing__(self, key):
    #Если нету нужного ключа

    self.__dict__[key] = type(self)()
    return self.__dict__[key]

'''...'''


if __name__=='__main__':

    struct = DictStruct()

    struct['userlist']['user']['name'] = 'Username' # +

    print(struct['userlist']['user']['age']) # - // Должно вернуть ошибку
```

Как узнать откуда был вызван метод класса и на при оделённых функциях делать дополнительные проверки

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900392/getting-the-caller-function-name-inside-another-function-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. `__getitem__` и `__setitem__`

В данном случае `__getitem__` и `__setitem__` не подойдут. Независимо от того, присваиваете вы значение в словарь последнего уровня или извлекаете, `__getitem__` всё равно будет вызываться по пути - для получения значений у словарей верхних уровней (1-го, 2-го и т.д.), через которые мы находим самый вложенный словарь, в котором собираемся менять элемент.

То есть ваша конструкция для записи нового элемента в словарь:

```
struct['userlist']['user']['name'] = 'Username'
```

работает следующим образом:

```
struct.__getitem__('userlist').__getitem__('user').__setitem__('name','Username')
```

- `struct.__getitem__('userlist')` - вызываем метод `__getitem__` у объекта `struct` и передаём ему `'userlist'`. В нашем случае метод должен вернуть словарь, назовём его `2_level_dict`.
- `2_level_dict.__getitem__('user')` - у полученного в предыдущем шаге словаря `2_level_dict` таким же способом получаем следующий словарь - `3_level_dict`.
- `3_level_dict.__setitem__('name','Username')` - в конце записываем новое значение в словарь `3_level_dict`.
- в результате получаем желаемый многоуровневый словарь: `{'userlist': {'user': {'name': 'Username'}}}`.

**Итого:** несмотря на то, что вы хотели записать значение, метод `__getitem__` вызывался два раза. Он вызывается всякий раз, когда происходит запрос элемента в словаре, а без запроса здесь не обойтись - нужно же добраться до самого вложенного словаря.

Переходим ко второй конструкции:

```
print(struct['userlist']['user']['age'])
```

"под капотом" она представляет собой следующее:

```
struct.__getitem__('userlist').__getitem__('user').__getitem__('age')
```

На данный момент `__getitem__` вместо того, чтобы выдать ошибку, не найдя элемент `'userlist'` в первом словаре, молча создаст новый словарь и присвоит его ключу `'userlist'`. Потом второй словарь - `'user'`. И т.д.

Чтобы вторая конструкция выдавала ошибку при отсутствии какого-либо элемента, нужно убирать дефолтное создание нового словаря `DictStruct` из `__getitem__`, а мы не можем, так как тогда перестанет работать первая.

**Замечание:** слово `struct` лучше не использовать - оно является ключевым в языке **C** и используется там очень часто. На работу программы написанной на **Python** это никак не влияет, но людям знакомым с **С** не удобно читать этот код. Мне во всяком случае.

### 2. Получение имени вызывающего объекта:

Для определения объекта из которого функция была вызвана, можно использовать модуль [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html):

```
import inspect
def foo():
    # возьми текущий фрейм объект (frame object)
    current_frame = inspect.currentframe()

    # получи фрейм объект, который его вызвал
    caller_frame = current_frame.f_back

    # возьми у вызвавшего фрейма исполняемый в нём объект типа "код" (code object)
    code_obj = caller_frame.f_code

    # и получи его имя
    code_obj_name = code_obj.co_name

    print("Имя вызывающего объекта: ", code_obj_name)

def a():
    foo()

def b():
    foo()

a()
b()
foo()
```

**Output**

```
Имя вызывающего объекта:  a
Имя вызывающего объекта:  b
Имя вызывающего объекта:  <module>
```

Сильно расписывать не буду, тут слишком многое надо объяснять, чтобы стало понятно. Что такое фрейм, что такое объект типа "код"...